# Bluetooth Fit Watch Connection Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bluetooth

i recently posted about connection to bluetooth devices using Xamarin. I managed to get the device and the mac address on a list. Im having a problem connecting to the device. It doesnt do anything when clicked... What are the next steps to pairing with device and is it even possible to pair with a fit watch, im trying to use the heart rate monitor on the fit watch as well.

I'm guessing the next step would be to setup a Click event on the list...
Something like

```
myListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
myListView.ItemClick += List_Click;
        private void List_Click(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

and is it possible to get the data from the fit watch and sync it with a chart.
I have managed to get a pie chart . now i just need to pair the fit watch and get the data from bluetooth. Any advice would be grateful thanks

Comment: You should specify which make/model of watch you are trying to communicate with as well as which SDK or are you using just standard Bluetooth Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a BluetoothDevice object from the `BluetoothAdapter`

and something like :

```
myListView.ItemClick += List_Click;
    private void List_Click(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

         var address = xxxxx; //the address you select
         BluetoothDevice btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address);
         var _socket = btDevice .CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
         _socket.Connect();
    }
```

Much of the specifics for handling paired devices is in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)